# Increase select speed on C# datable which is loaded from unindexed view

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I've run into a performance issue with a routine which synchronises two databases.

As part of the process, we load a `DataTable` from a select on a view in the client DB.

We then iterate over a `Dictionary` containing all the records in our own DB, and perform a select on the `DataTable` using a key taken from the `Dictionary`.

As there is no index on the `DataTable` (the view isn't indexed, and we do not deliberately add an index), the process is painfully slow, and is now causing a major concern.

I'm trying to determine the most effective way to increase the search speed on the data table, while trying to minimise the amount of changes needed.

We cannot use a stored procedure for this process, nor can the sync routine be re-written at this stage. It does what it should do, just very slowly.

I have looked at the possibility of using a `DataView` with the column we select on as a primary key, but cannot find any solid information on whether this will yield a performance increase.

Obfuscated code below - there is more going on in the `foreach` loop than shown, and the structure of this cannot be changed due to existing code which must be unaltered`:

```
using (DataTable ClientDbDocuments = GetAllClientDbDocuments()) {
     Dictionary<int, int> docsInOurDb = GetAllDocumentsInOurDb();
     if (docsInOurDb.Count > 0) {
     foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in docsInOurDb) {
         int ClientRecordKey = kvp.Value;
         int OurRecordKey = kvp.Key;
         DataRow[] rows = ClientDbDocuments.Select("RecordKey = " + ClientRecordKey);
         if (rows.Length == 0) {
            //Candidate keys is a List<Int32>
            candidateKeys.Add(OurRecordKey);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Possible solutions I have considered are shown below, but I'm not sure if this will be much of an improvement.
As there are a number of methods where the select must be run, it would be preferable to apply any change to the DataTable at the point it is initially loaded (in `GetAllClientDbDocuments`).

Possible Options:
 1. Create an index on the `DataTable` using a `DataView`, then select from the `DataView` (unsure if this will speed up the select)
 2. Create a `Dictionary` using the search column name as the key, with the `DataRow` as the value (More work than ideal, but would do the job)

Out of those options listed, which would be most suited to speeding up the select, or is there another option which can be applied in this instance?

Comment: If all it's doing is synchronizing two databases consider using a stored proc instead, if it's an option. Would be much faster.

Comment: We can't use a stored procedure in this case, as the DBs are locate don different servers and the search has some complex logic determining which candidates can be synchronised that would not translate well to a T-Sql script. The issue here is specifically about increasing the speed of searching the DataTable.